# My custom RegisterSerializer doesn't work with django-rest-auth

Tags: django

I'm using `django-rest-auth` and I want to add registration with my own User model. So I add `allauth` and create my own RegisterSerializer as it was mentioned in docs.

apps/users/serializers.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if email and email_address_exists(email):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
        return email

    def validate_password(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'password': self.validated_data.get('password', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', '')
        }

    def save(self, request):
        user = get_user_model()
        cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        user.create_user(**cleaned_data)
        return user
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'django_extensions',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',

    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',


    'apps.users'
]
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
     'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.RegisterSerializer',
}
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Unfortunately `django-allauth` still uses the default serializer

Answer (score 5):

Instead of,

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'apps.users.serializers.RegisterSerializer',
}
```

use;

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'apps.users.serializers.RegisterSerializer',
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ADD`SITE_ID = 1` in settings.py and `'rest_auth.registration',` in your installed apps of settings.py file and change

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.RegisterSerializer',
}
```

to

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'apps.users.serializers.RegisterSerializer',
}
```

Comment: @JanardhanReddyMeeniga even with `apps` it doesn't work

Comment: @Ernst add  'allauth',  'allauth.account', in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @JenardhanReddy I've updated my question with settings